# Django channels consumer how to disconnect at server side

Tags: django, websocket, channel

I'm trying to write a log file viewer with django, channels, but only the first connection works well, while I refresh the frontend, websocket will connect fail. After some search, I found the loop is still running in my code(the first websocket connection not cleaned up rightly). I was thinking that `disconnect` would be called when I close the websocket client, but it's not.

My consumer code:

```
import time
from channels.exceptions import StopConsumer
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
class LogConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    end = False
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()
        filename = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['filepath']
        file_fullname = "/tmp/" + filename
        print('file name: %s' % file_fullname)
        with open(file_fullname, 'r') as f:
           while True:
               time.sleep(1)
               if self.end:
                   break
               new_line = f.readline()
               print('Loop is still running ....')
               if new_line:
                   print('sending data: %s' % new_line)
                   self.send(text_data=new_line)

    def disconnect(self, event):
        print('websocket disconnected...', event)
        self.end = True
        raise StopConsumer()
```

daphne output:

```
192.168.1.2:63267 - - [03/Jun/2023:16:25:09] "WSCONNECTING /ws/message/" - -
192.168.1.2:63267 - - [03/Jun/2023:16:25:09] "WSCONNECT /ws/message/" - -
file name: /tmp/message
Loop is still running ....
sending data:

Loop is still running ....
sending data: 1

Loop is still running ....
sending data: 2

Loop is still running ....
sending data: 3

192.168.1.2:63267 - - [03/Jun/2023:16:25:14] "WSDISCONNECT /ws/message/" - -
192.168.1.2:63273 - - [03/Jun/2023:16:25:14] "WSCONNECTING /ws/message/" - -
Loop is still running ....
sending data: 4

Loop is still running ....
sending data: 5
```

Comment: Finally resolved by rewriting loop block in a thread, and I understand the reason is loop blocked in `send()`.

Answer (score 0):

The consumer is blocked by the loop in `send()`. So I rewrite loop in thread. Resolved.

The fixed code is like:

```
class LogConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    end = False
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.action)
        self.thread.start()

    def action(self):
        filename = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['filepath']
        file_fullname = "/tmp/" + filename
        print('file name: %s' % file_fullname)
        with open(file_fullname, 'r') as f:
           while not self.end:
               if self.end:
                   break
               new_line = f.readline()
               # print('Loop is still running ....')
               if new_line:
                   print('sending data: %s' % new_line)
                   self.send(text_data=new_line)

    def disconnect(self, event):
        print('websocket disconnected...', event)
        self.end = True
        raise StopConsumer()
```